# Python what does def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse: mean?

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm playing with Azure Functions and the main method is

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
```

Can someone please break down every part of this and explain what it means. Specifically what does `req: func.HttpRequest` mean, is it forcing some data type for the parameter?
And what does `-> func.HttpResponse` mean, is it forcing a return type?

I've never seen this syntax in Python before.

Comment: The phrase you should Google is: Python Annotations

Comment: You are seeing annotations and type hinting.  `req` is a required positional argument. `: func.HttpRequest` is a type hint telling the user what `req` should be.  In this case an HTTP request object.  The trailing bit `-> func.HttpResponse` is another annotation telling you what the function returns.  In this case an HTTP Response object.

Comment: [Typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Answer (score 4):

It defines a function named `main`, which takes one parameter named `req` that is of type `func.HttpRequest`, and returns a value of type `func.HttpResponse`.